# I want to use an image for a submit button url to be defined by $pic

Tags: php, html, xhtml

I am trying to use a variable image for a submit button the example below works with a fixed image

```
<input type="image" src="/images/submit.gif" width="120" height="30" border="0" alt="SUBMIT!" />
```

What I want to do is use `$pic` instead of `/images/submit.gif`

any offers ?

Answer (score 4):

```
SRC="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($pic); ?>"
```